# Why C# doesn't support overloading based on return type

Tags: c#-4.0

In C# why can't we have two functions with same signature except return type:

(1) int Function(int a,int b)
    {
      ---}
(2) string Function(int a,int b)
    {
      ---}

Why C# doesn't support overloading based on return type?

Answer (score 2):

`object result = Function(a, b);`

Which one do you call?

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't specify the return type when you call it.

```
// int or string?
Function(a, b);
```

I'm also curious why you would want to do this, naming something the same but returning two different things is probably a bad idea. This code is far more readable and the intent is clearer:

```
string x = FunctionToString(a, b);
int y = FunctionToInt(a, b);
```